# How to add legend to an aster plot d3 js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on recreating the Aster plot given in the example given below:

http://bl.ocks.org/bbest/2de0e25d4840c68f2db1

I changed the coloring of the arcs with the code given below:

```
var fill = d3.scale.category10();
```

Now I am trying to display the legends of the graph with the code given below. I am not getting the legends plotted. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(fill.domain())
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  // draw legend colored rectangles
  legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", fill);

  // draw legend text
  legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) { return d.id;})
```

Comment: Are you running this before drawing the actual plot? It needs to be after that.

Comment: I am running this after the actual plot. This block is the last one in my code.

Comment: Could you post the complete code you're running please?

Comment: http://paste.fedoraproject.org/159840/86536431/

Comment: Well it looks like the code to fill the `rect`s should be `.style("fill", function(d) { return d; })`, but apart from that it should work. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I made the change and ran it again. Still not working out. I am not getting any error messages.

Comment: Well the main problem was that you weren't creating the legend in a position where you could actually see it. Fixed [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YWwb47049UHbqRTpFKxc?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was your positioning of the legend -- it was obscured by other elements. In addition, it's better to use `d.data.label` to determine the colour as that gives you access to the labels you want to use for the legend in the domain of the colour scale.

I've fixed this and a few minor issues [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YWwb47049UHbqRTpFKxc?p=preview).